# Make an input concave from right and convex from left

Tags: css, input, css-shapes

How can I achieve that effect on text input with css?

[image: input]

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: This can be done but please show us your effort.

Comment: @Harry, is it possible to show what you mean by how this can be done?  It don't know where to start and would love to see this as well.

Comment: That's what i have, and now I'm stuck: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/8pe6cg91/)

Comment: @razorsyntax: Pseudo-elements cannot be added to an `input` tag and hence it needs to be wrapped within a container (like in the below answer) and concave effect cannot be achieved with only border-radius, so we should use box shadows (or) make the pseudo-elements to round shape and position them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap `input` and use `pseudo` element to make it `curved` for curved shadow you can use `inset` `box-shadow` and for `input` you can add `padding`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 92%;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 0px 0px 0px rgb(184, 170, 170);
}
div input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
  background: #343434;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 3px 0px rgb(184, 170, 170);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: why -ve can you please explain?